# Замена картинки для разделов и тем форума

Tags: php

Приветствую форумчане.
Написал форум. 3 файла/страницы.
1 - разделы форума
2 - темы для разделов
3 - сообщения для тем
в таблицу для тем в бд записываю id раздела,
id, nick авторов последних сообщений и прочее.
в таблицу для сообщений в бд записываю
id темы   id, nick автора сообщения и дату.
Есть 2 вида картинок:
для разделов:
1 картинка - новые сообщения в теме(ах) для раздела
2 картинка - нет новых сообщений в теме(ах) для раздела
для тем также

Нужно сделать:
1. для разделов показать 1 картинку если есть новые сообщения в темах и id автора последнего сообщения не равен id с сессии
2. для разделов показать 2 картинку если есть новые сообщения в темах и id автора последнего сообщения совпадает с id с сессии
3. для тем сделать аналогично 1 и 2 пункту
4. так как и разделы и темы выводятся в виде ссылок, то при переходе по ссылке 1 картинку изменить на 2
Весь гугл перекопал, но все не то.
Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать это замысел..
P.S. что не понятно, скажите, дополню

```js
// вывод ссылок для разделов
<?php if ($us_ses_role == 'user') : ?>
 <?php $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM forum_sections WHERE status = '0'");
 while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) :
  $GLOBALS['res_id'] = $result['id']; 
  $GLOBALS['res_title'] = $result['section_title']; ?>

  <div class="link">
    <a href="themes?id=<?= $res_id; ?>"><?= $res_title; ?></a>
  </div><br>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($us_ses_role == 'admin' || $us_ses_role == 'moderator') : ?>
 <?php $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM forum_sections");
 while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) :
  $GLOBALS['res_id'] = $result['id']; 
  $GLOBALS['res_title'] = $result['section_title']; ?>

  <div class="link">
   <a href="themes?id=<?= $res_id; ?>"><?= $res_title; ?></a>
  </div><br>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?> 


// вывод ссылок для тем
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_subsections WHERE section_id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $section_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) :
 $GLOBALS['res_id'] = $result['id']; 
 $GLOBALS['res_title'] = $result['title'];
 $GLOBALS['res_autor_id'] = $result['autor_id'];
 $GLOBALS['res_autor_nick'] = $result['autor_nick']; ?>
 <div class="link">
  <a href="/topic?id=<?= $res_id; ?>&page=1"><?= $res_title; ?></a>
 </div><br>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: В вашем коде я не увидел ни одной картинки. Ссылки - да, картинки - нет. Как так получилось?

Comment: убрал. толку пока с них мало. картинки будут стоять перед ссылками